# How do I strip the null byte from a string in R?

Tags: r, string, null

How do I strip the null byte from a string in R?
Something like this:

```
> gsub('\0', '', 'doot\0')
Error: embedded nul in string: '\0'
```

Comment: R strings are like C strings, they are null terminated. You might need to look at raw vectors.

Comment: It turns out this wasn't actually the problem that I needed to solve.  The `embedded nul in string` error was triggered by a failure of URLdecode to handle unencoded percent symbols, e.g. `URLdecode('% xx')`; I thought the string being passed to URLdecode contained the null byte.  I worked around it with a [modified URLdecode](http://bit.ly/fRpVG2).

Comment: I was dealing with the same issue today ... the function url_decode from the package urltools deals with the 'unencoded percent symbols' problem